# pack() dont work in my PHP. I need convert int to byte

Tags: php, byte, pack

```
$fp = fopen('./test.dat','a+');
$a = 123123;
$b = ($a & 0xFF00) >> 8;
$b = pack('c',$b);
fwrite($fp,$b)
fclose($fp);
```

When i working this code, maybe i get value `'e0'` , but i get `'ce b0'`. What does matter this code?

Comment: Where is your $c?

Comment: Just typing error ..

Answer (score 0):

Pack will get the char, you need to use dechex to get the e0 like this: here is the **[live demo](https://eval.in/734438)**

```
<?php
$a = 123123;
echo $a;
echo "\n";
$b = ($a & 0xFF00) >> 8;
echo $b;
echo "\n";
$c = dechex($b);
$b = pack('c',$b);
echo $b;
echo "\n";
echo $c;
```

output:

```
123123
224
�
e0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get wrong data when i use fwrite().